# Align text vertically in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to do this in flutter.

[image]

I am trying to align the text inside container vertically.Just increased the height of container but it was not working. it camed like this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCqV6.png]

Code :

[image]

[image]

Comment: your code is missing

Comment: Please provide minimum producible code.

Comment: Rotate it around Z axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use RotatedBox Widget

```
RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: 3,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text("Rotated Text"),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using below code snippet:

```
import dart.math;
Transform.rotate(
angle: math.pi *15 /90
```

// Set degree as per requirement
child :CustomWidget()
)